# Why are commutators the first choice in describing observables that cannot be measured simultaneously?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator, quantization, foundations

In quantum mechanics, we convert Poisson brackets to commutators for the observables to account for the uncertainty principle. However, I do not understand why do we do this.

- What motivates us to choose commutators?
- Why not anti-commutators or some other mathematical structure?
- How does uncertainty in simultaneous measurements of certain observables lead to commutation relations?

Comment: It is a consequence of the Dirac postulate. In a quantum measurement, the post-measurement state is an eigenstate of the observable(A) you are measuring. Now if you want to measure an incompatible observable for this post-measurement state, it better not be an eigenstate of the new observable(B). This condition is satisfied only if [A,B] doesn't equal to 0

Comment: Anti-commutators are important in quantum theories describing fermions like QFT.

Comment: Agree with @Arnab.  The Dirac Quantization Condition is a fundamental postulate of QM (like the Principle of Extremized Action, often referred to as the Principle of Least Action, is a fundamental postulate of classical mechanics).  Heisenberg Uncertainty is a _consequence_ of the DQC, not the other way around.  If memory serves, https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9907069v2 is a good resource for reading more about how uncertainty manifests.  Also agree with @Charlie; see also anyons in 2+1D QFTs.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/573908